# Focus on TextBox before text gets entered C#

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to set the focus on a textbox using the below methods:

```
Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += HandleKeyDown;
Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().CharacterReceived += HandleCharacter;
```

But the problem is the characters reach the screen before the textbox gets focused and so do not display properly. Is there a way to delay the characters from appearing before the textbox is focused?

Putting a Delay in HandleKeyDown sure delays the method but that does not stop  CharacterReceived while the delay is still in progress.

Thanks

```
public void HandleKeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow window, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs e)

{

 if (e.VirtualKey== Windows.System.VirtualKey.F12)

{

//do something here for the characters that follow this key

Task.Delay(500);

//this task gets delayed but the other characters that follows f12 keypress keep showing up in the screen.
```

}

}

Comment: Could you not use ```FocusManager.FocusedElement``` attached property instead?

Comment: Thanks. Looking for something like onkeydown focus on the element, get the characters without showing up on the screen and set it to the element that way it is consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to take care of this using

```
KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor kbinterceptor = KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor.GetForCurrentView();
kbinterceptor.IsInterceptionEnabledWhenInForeground = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Shown event of main form. In this method you put for example Textbox1. Focus=True. For example

```
Private void frmMainProgram_Shown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) {
    TextBox1.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with keyup property. It will give some delay and focus on keyup

CoreWindow.KeyUp

Comment: It is not reliable. Gives different results each time.